# Request Blocked on WAMP, but CORS allowed on XAMPP

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, xampp, cors, wampserver

I try to call a jpg file that stored on XAMPP port `8012` using WAMP, sending an XHR from port `8080`.

I have an `htaccess` file on the XAMPP server with the following content, In order to allow CORS:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Content-Type"

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
</IfModule>
```

and I even tried to edit the configuration file `httpd.conf` file [with this guide](https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html), but nothing works. WAMP sends a `GET` request and receiving the following error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at http://localhost:8012/cdn_8080/video.jpg.
>   (Reason: missing token 'access-control-allow-origin' in CORS header
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' from CORS preflight channel).

I checked, and `mod_rewrite` is enabled on xampp:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem.

My Javascript file contained the following lines:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
// xhr.withCredentials = true;
// will return an error
```

and it's unnecessary, so I removed them and now everything works great.

Comment: Can confirm. Do not know why.